# Don't delete leading space after org-insert-link

Tags: org-mode

When I do `org-insert-link` and input a link description the space before the description gets deleted. Can this be prevented?

Example:

I type: **"see "** (i.e. with space), then hit `C-c C-l`, insert link, description: **"here"**. 
The result is:
**"seehere"** instead of intended **"see here"** (with space between the words).

Comment: I can't reproduce this on Emacs 25.1.50 and Org 8.2.10. If you start from `emacs -Q`, does this still happen? What versions of emacs and org-mode are you running (`M-x emacs-version` and `M-x org-version`)?

Comment: I can't reproduce that on Emacs 24.5.50.1 and org mode 8.3.4-31. Did you try `emacs -Q`?

Comment: Also could not reproduce on Emacs 24.3.1 and org 7.9.3f

Comment: OK, so it seems it is caused by something in my config, because emacs -Q works... Anybody has experience which setting could be a culprit? I'll try to diagnose it in the evening.